# using python how to convert numeric data in ordinal?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, ordinal

data :

```
118.6
109.7
126.7
107.8
113.9
109.7
109.7
98.2
112.3
153.7
157.8
85
126.7
125.1
155.4
138.5
154.6
189.9
120.6
101.6
128.7
138.5
210.8
124.4
189.8
122.5
161.7
188.6
229.1
168.7
233.7
137.5
126.6
244.4
141.9
227.5
183
177.6
244.4
95.1
116.4
75.9
75.3
109.8
117.1
75.9
109.8
71.2
71.3
89.6
93.3
84.7
85
82.9
145.3
107.7
84.2
96.7
89.8
86.2
85
89.6
67.5
64.9
48.1
54.9
56.1
60.6
51
44.6
64.3
57.6
66.2
69
60
70.2
65.4
60.1
49.4
61.4
62.8
78.8
70.3
82.7
68.6
```

I want to convert this numeric data in to ordinal .

Example :
if data values are comes in  60 to 69.9 then it will show me 1.

if data values are comes in  70 to 79.9 then it will show me 2.

if data values are comes in  80 to 89.9 then it will show me 3.

if data values are comes in  90 to 99.9 then it will show me 4. so on.

I know how to binarize data,  using `binaryX = binarizer.transform(X)`
but i don't know how to convert numeric interval values in single ordinal value.

Comment: Use map function on list : data.map(yourTransformFunction)

Comment: @StefanPochmann , oops it was 89.9 & 99.9 typo .sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about just dividing by 10, and subtracting the offset?

```
data = ['60', '69.9', '70', '73', '80']
[int((float(a) // 10) - 5) for a in data]                          # [1, 1, 2, 2, 3]
```

or, if you are using NumPy

```
((numpy.array([float(a) for a in data]) // 10) - 5).astype(int)    # [1 1 2 2 3]
```

Comment: I get error :     [(a // 10) - 5 for a in data]
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for //: 'str' and 'int'

Comment: cast the data to float using `float()`. See my edit.

Comment: when I run first one  , than I  get   >>> [int((float(a) // 10) - 5) for a in data  output : [6]

Comment: >>> [int((float(a) // 10) - 5) for a in data]                          # [1, 1,
[6]
>>>

Comment: Pretty hard to reproduce without some actual testdata.

Comment: your code is working ,  >>> (data  //10) - 5 , this one but some numbers gives me negative sign